# Delphi Indy Sharepoint Windows Login

Tags: delphi, sharepoint, indy

I am including these in **uses** clause

```
  IdAuthentication
  ,
  IdAuthenticationDigest
  ,
  IdAuthenticationNTLM
  ,
  IdAuthenticationSSPI
```

Currently I have code that does this:

```
    W.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
    W.Request.Username := AOptionsPtr^.AuthUsername;
    W.Request.Password := AOptionsPtr^.AuthPassword;
```

And if I have access to OpenSSL:

```
    TmpOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
    //--
    W.IOHandler := TmpOpenSSL;
```

From skimming the documentation for WinINet (yes, I know it is not Indy) it seems persistent connections is also required for authentication. I suppose this also goes for Indy? URL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384220(v=vs.85).aspx

I need to get this to work with SharePoint. The problem, however, is hat I have no intranet SharePoint server to test against. Thus I can not step through the code and see what works and what does not. However, I have a potential customer that can test it for me.

What more do I need to do to get above code working with SharePoint using Windows Authentication (NTML? SPPI?)

Will Indy automatically test and use proper auhentication?

do I need to set `W.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;` for auto authentication/detection to work?

If multiple requests are necessary (with first response being 401) I assume I need to add support for this in my own code when making a GET request? (To set authentication mode and make a new request?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request a persistent connection by setting the `Request.Connection` property to `'keep-alive'`.

TIdHTTP will check the server's `WWW-Authorization` header and compare it to the `TIdAthentication` classes you have included in your `uses` clause.  The `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event will tell you which class was picked, and allow you to override it if needed.  The `TIdHTTP.OnAuthorization` event will be triggered if authentication fails and different credentials are needed.

The `BasicAuthrnication` property simply allows `TIdHTTP` to fall back to `TIdBasicAuthentication` if no other `TIdAuthentication` class is assigned.

No, you do not need to handle multi-request authentications manually, like NTLM.  `TIdHTTP` and `TIdAuthentication` handle those details for you.

Comment: Hi Remy. Thanks for your answer. I will try it out. If I prefill username/password I won't need to handle the event if I understand you correctly? (Assuming I trust Indy to select the correct authentication type... Which I do.) If I still want BasicAuthentication as backup, should I set Request.BasicAuthentication to false? (Will Indy then automatically use it as backup incase authentication does not match any of the other?)

Comment: The user/pass values you fill in are used in the initial auth request. If the server rejects them and asks for auth again, the `OnAuthorization` event allows you to change the values, even optionally prompt the user for them. You have to set `BasicAuthentication` to true top enable the fallback.